# Can not load a webpage from app A but can load from app B

Tags: android, android-webview

I am an android developer, I created an android application (application A) recently,
My application is able to load a web page (webPage X) normally. But Recently, my application couldn't load webpage X any more, webpage display error message

> "The webpage at xxx could not be loaded because : net:
>   ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED."

I created another application (application B -same source code as app A but different package name), this application can load webpage X very well.
Here is the code for loading the webpage.

```
webview = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("http:// xxx")
```

Could you help to solve this problem in app A

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the url http or https?

Comment: the destination web site is is http

Comment: `http` is *probably* a problem

Comment: android doesn't like HTTP anymore due to security concerns. HTTPS is what every network call has to be in

Answer (score 0):

add https instead of http

```
webview = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("https:// xxx")
```

Comment: No. The destination website is http NOT https